# Same list in two different containers

Tags: jquery, html

Can we display a single list in two different columns i.e. two different containers Or a single div but different columns?

```
<div>
<ul>
<li>HTML</li>
<li>CSS</li>
</div>
<div>
<li>javascript</li>
<li>jquery</li>
</div>
```

I want the above to appear as:

HTML javascript 
CSS  jquery

Also the elements in first column may vary and if the elements decrease the elements from the second column must occupy the entire space.

Comment: put the html along with question

Comment: you need to add more explanation.. please add some html code to the question..

Answer (score 0):

No you can not (edit: cut the list off in the middle as in your suggested HTML). What you *can* do is create two separate lists, but if what you're after is for the list to appear as:

```
1. HTML 2. javascript 3. CSS 4. jquery
```

I fail to understand why you simply don't just put the items in that order and display the `li`s as 'inline`?

If in fact you want the list to appear as:

```
1. HTML 3. JavaScript
2. CSS 4. jQuery
```

And the order of the items is "1. HTML, 2. CSS, 3. JavaScript, 4. jQuery" you will need to use `column-count: 2` on the `ul`. This will place the list items in columns where the first two items will be in the left column, and the last two items in the right column. `column-count` only works in modern browsers so for the rest you'll need to use `float` or `inline-block` which will make the list appear as:

```
1. HTML 2. CSS
3. JavaScipt 4. jQuery
```

Comment: i already know column post and li inline solution. Are you definite that it cannot be achieved?

Comment: You can not use the HTML you suggested in your question, no.